# Recoding character values that are only part of entire value

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I am trying to recode a value in a column that can have multiple text values. I am trying to recode everything in my "source" column that reads "BBC News" to "BBC News - Africa". I got the code to work with observations where BBC News is the ONLY value. However, I need the recode to work in observations where there are other sources in addition to BBC News. "Recent" is my dataframe.

Here is my code for recoding:

'''
recode(Recent$source, "BBC News" = "BBC News - Africa")
'''

Comment: `sub('.*BBC News.*', 'BBC News - Africa')`

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by "need the recode to work in observations where there are other sources in addition to BBC News". How are these "otehr sources" represented in the data object. Please post an example that creates an R data object to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use str_replace()

Toy dataframe:

```
Recent<-data.frame(a=1:4, source=c("BBC News", "BBC News - Africa", "BBC News - International", "NBC News"))

> Recent
  a                   source
1 1                 BBC News
2 2        BBC News - Africa
3 3 BBC News - International
4 4                 NBC News
```

Mutate with string::str_replace:

```
Recent%>%
        mutate(source=stringr::str_replace(source,
                                           ".*BBC News.*",
                                           "BBC News"))
  a   source
1 1 BBC News
2 2 BBC News
3 3 BBC News
4 4 NBC News
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update (See the valuable comment of GuedesBF)**

With the toy data from GuedesBF(many thanks).
We could use `ifelse` and `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Recent %>% 
  mutate(source = ifelse(str_detect(source, "BBC News"),  "BBC News", source))
```

Output:

```
  a   source
1 1 BBC News
2 2 BBC News
3 3 BBC News
4 4 NBC News
```

Comment: there is only one condition here. Would not a simple `ifelse(str_detect(source, "BBC News", "BBC News", source)` be enough?
`str_detect` is also compatible with tidyverse synthax, would not you prefer to use `str_detect(source, ...)` instead of `str_detect(Recent$source, ...)`?

Comment: That said, your solution seems very reasonable, especially if the OP has many patterns to replace in his real dataset

Comment: Good point. Thank you you are right. Please see my edit.